# Apple account for customizing maximo anywhere applications

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am using Maximo anywhere 7.6.3 and wanted to know if we need an apple account to customize (i.e add new fields) to existing application. The customization guide of 7.6.2 says it is needed for building iphone applications, but then not sure if it is required for the latest version. The modifications that i made in dev. work as expected though.

Answer (score 0):

in order to compile to IOS, you don't need a developer account, just XCODE and a MAC. In order to distribute the app via the app store, you would need a developer account.

Answer (score 0):

IBM publishes out of the box Anywhere applications to both the Google Play and Apple app stores, so you can point them at your Anywhere server and deploy a lot of changes that way without the need for an Apple account.

If you want to make changes to the iOS apps like custom app icons, custom app names or baking in the server url and then distribute the app either publicly or within your organisation, then you will need an Apple developer/enterprise account.

Comment: Thanks John. The way we have set up is that the users download the app. from Apple app store and then connect to the anywhere server which then updates the app on the phone. Would i need an account even if i am making small changes like enabling/disabling GPS, change logo or add a new field on the screen? The build command makes the wlapp files (no ipa files are created) without any issues if i add a new field or change the logo in the project.

Comment: Hi Mave, yes I believe all 3 use cases you state would be supported here. With logos this will only be inside the application i.e. from the login screen onwards, not the app icons.

Comment: For clarity, by supported I mean no apple account required - the changes described would be built into the .wlapp file and be distributed using mobilefirst's direct update feature.

Comment: Thanks john for the clarification.